# Append Script file on HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I append script dynamically on html file, i put alert on my js file and its working. But the problem is document.write(); is not working anymore. Here is my code:

For the JS file: LANG_EN.js

```
alert("en");
var lang = {
  "USERNAME":"USERNAME",
  "PASSWORD":"PASSWORD",
};
```

common.js

```
function createScript(id) {
  var elementID = id;
  var area = document.getElementById(elementID),

  script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = 'js/lang_en.js';
  area.innerHTML = '';
  area.appendChild(script); // Append it
}

createScript('languagefile');
```

HTML file:

```
<label for="username">document.write(lang.USERNAME);</label>
```

if i dont append the script the document.write is working properly.

I want to append it so that i can control the languages for all contents.

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: `<label for="username">document.write(lang.USERNAME);</label>` This will print "document.write(lang.USERNAME);"

Comment: If you use `document.write` _after_ the page is finished loading, you tell the browser to erase the whole document. This is defined behavior: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write

Answer (score 1):

try putting it inside an script tag or add id on yout label like this

`<label for="username" id="username"></label>
<script>
document.getElementById('username').innerHTML = lang.USERNAME;
</script>`